# using color to dfferentiate format specifiers from rest of string

Tags: c, colors, format, themes

I'm new to coding (Using Eclipse for C/C++ development) and while I'm trying to learn it I was attempting to mess with some color values to make it easier on myself to read. One of the things I wanted to change the most was how format specifiers like `%d` keep the same coloring as the rest of the string they are contained in.  For example in a line like this

```
printf("You are %d years old", age);
```

I would want the `%d` to be a separate color from `"you are years old"` so that I can easily see at a glance where in the code it is.  This more comes into play when there are multiple `\n` `\t` or `%d` values thrown in a single line of code.  As far as I can tell there is no way to separate them as changing the color for `"string"` changes the entire string, `%d` included.  If anyone knows a way around this it would be much appreciated.

I've tried several different themes none of which addressed this issue, also online searching seems to be futile on this topic.

Comment: This is something your IDE/code editor to handle. But you don't even mention which one you are using. FWIW, VIM is doing this for me...

Comment: You have to mention your IDE to answer this question correctly. But I worked with eclispe/visual studio based IDEs and I believe most of IDEs has path `Windows -> Preferences -> <your programming language> -> Code Style or Editor`. But your IDE might have separate code style editor (like Microchip Studio) so you have to try or update your question.

Comment: @Wartiik appologies, somehow that skipped my mind to mention.  I currently use eclipse